# how does one load a div using its id to a view?

Tags: codeigniter

how does one load a div using its id to a view?

this is my view

```
  <div id="register" class="animate form">
    <section class="login_content">
      <form <?php echo form_open('User/register'); ?>
        <h1>Create Account</h1>
       <div class="inputlogin">

    <div class="form-group">
```

how will i pass it to

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() === false) {

        // validation not ok, send validation errors to the view


        $index['title']="Welcome to Hoovie";
        $index['mainContent']="login";
        $index['results'] = $this->users_model->get_category();
        $this->load->view('includes/redirect', $index, $data);
```

Comment: Can you explain more? So i can give an answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, form_open tag makes  `<form>`  so you can't echo it inside of form it would look like `<form <form>>`

here is example of login form inside of view:

```
echo form_open('path/to/controller');
    echo form_input(array(
          'name'        => 'username',
          'class'          => 'form-control input-lg',
          'placeholder'       => 'username'
        ));

    echo form_password(array(
          'name'        => 'password',
          'class'          => 'form-control input-lg',
          'placeholder'       => 'password'
        ));


    echo form_submit(array(
          'name'        => 'LoginSubmit',
          'class'          => 'btn btn-lg btn-info',
          'value'       => 'Login'
        ));

echo form_close();}
```

After that inside of your controller you have to activate form_validation library if it is not auto-loaded and then you have to set rules for your inputs

example :

```
    $dugme = $this->input->post('LoginSubmit');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');     


        if(isset($dugme) && $this->form_validation->run()){
        //if everything ok, do something
        }
    else {
  //if validation did not pass load view 
    $this->load_view('login'); }
```

and after that inside of view you have to echo errors

```
//I am using bootstrap so alert-danger will show this div with red background 
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">','</div>');?>
```

you can check more about form validation here :

> Codeigniter 3: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html
>   Codeigniter 2: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html